# Android WebView partial HTML rendering problem

Tags: android, html, webview

My HTML is very simple and it should be rendered like this

[image]

However android webview loses some of the content and renders it like this

[image]

The line that is causing the problem is this
`<a name="_ftnref1" href="#_ftn1">[1]</a>`

How do I tweak HTML or the webview so that everything is rendered correctly?

**MainActivity.kt**

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.webkit.WebView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val html = """
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <body>
                <ul>
                    <li>content above link</li>
                    <li>The link is on this line 
                        <a name="_ftnref1" href="#_ftn1">[1]</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>content below link</li>
                </ul>
                <p>
                    <a name="_ftn1" href="#_ftnref1">[1]</a> Link landing
                </p>
            </body>
        </html>
    """.trimIndent()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        findViewById<WebView>(R.id.web_view).loadData(html, "text/html", "UTF-8")
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strangely, I solved my problem by loading html content from file rather than from memory. Why it works this way and doesn't work the other way I have no idea.

```
// HTML will be rendered correctly
val file = File(filesDir, "temp.html")
file.writeText(html, Charset.forName("UTF-8"))

val webView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.web_view)
webView.settings.allowFileAccess = true
webView.loadUrl("file://" + file.absolutePath)

// HTML will be rendered incorrectly
// webView.loadData(html, "text/html", "UTF-8")
```

Comment: Has the same issue, the # was breaking the rendering.
this solution worked for me, thank you for sharing

Answer (score 0):

Try to at this to your activity_main.xml

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
      android:normalScreens="true" 
      android:largeScreens="true"
  android:anyDensity="true" />
```